# PyQt get data out of signal

Tags: python

I have managed to connect a signal between a UI class and a worker thread class, where the UI class emits an object as below. The idea is to send **twist** from the **UI** class to the **PubThread** class.

```
self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('msg'), twist)
```

My worker thread recieves this signal as it enters the callback function, but I cannot use the data in the signal. Here is my abridged worker.

```
@singleton
class PubThread(QtCore.QThread):

    def __init__(self):
        print "Initing thread"
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.msg = QtCore.pyqtSignal(Twist, name = 'msg')
    

    def connect_slots(self, sender):
        self.connect(sender, QtCore.SIGNAL('msg'), self.publish)

    def publish(self):
        print rospy.loginfo(self.msg)
```

How can I access the underlying data from the signal? I get an error at the moment saying that self.msg is not the correct type, and is currently an unbound message.

Thanks

### EDIT

If I move the self.msg = QtCore... line outside the constructor, I get a similar error but now its a bound message.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by changing my worker thread to the following:

```
@singleton
```

class PubThread(QtCore.QThread):

```
msg = QtCore.pyqtSignal(Twist, name = 'msg')

def __init__(self):
    print "Initing thread"
    QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
    self.pub = rospy.Publisher('husky/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=100)
    rospy.init_node('pyGui', anonymous=True)
    self.rate = rospy.Rate(10)



def connect_slots(self, sender):
    print "Connected apparently"
    self.connect(sender, QtCore.SIGNAL('msg'), self.publish)

def publish(self, value):
    print rospy.loginfo(value)
    self.pub.publish(value)
    self.rate.sleep()
```